# Extracting data from dynamically created tags with the ng-model directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to use the same `ng-model` directive multiple times and access them uniquely?

I have a directive that populates the page with multiple instances of a single template. Since it's the same template, all of the `ng-model` attributes that get added point to the same variable in the controller.

I'm currently using `document.getElementsByName()` so I get a list that can be iterated through, but there's more clutter when trying to get the data that way versus simply referencing the variable in the controller.

EDIT:

This HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <tib-copy></tib-copy>
</div>
```

Gets the injection and becomes this:

```
<tib-copy>
    <fieldset class="col-md-2" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
        <legend>Copy</legend>

        <input type="text" ng-model="searchOptions.sourceServer">
        <br/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchOptions.sourcePath">
        <br/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchOptions.destServer">
        <br/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchOptions.destPath">
    </fieldset>
</tib-copy>
```

Doing it once more (click of a button that calls the function to do the injection via `ng-click`) will cause the same `ng-model` tags to be repeated in the DOM.

As an example, I want to get all `ng-model` attributes of `"searchOptions.sourceServer"` as a list or something that allows me to extract the values individually. But what happens is all of the text fields are updated with identical values because of the two-way binding.

Comment: Could you provide the html/template code. Are you creating these tags inside of a `ng-repeat`?

Comment: @The.Bear I added an example

Answer (score 1):

For that purpose, you need to use `ngModelController` for your `tibCopy` directive. It means that every models you define in it, served as local directive models. You will then have to parse them into higher level `ngModel` that you pass on rendering the directive into other components.

For example, you can start with the following directive structures:

```js
  App.directive('tbpCopy', 
      function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        templateUrl: '<fieldset class="col-md-2" style="margin-bottom: 10px">' +
                      '<legend>Copy</legend>' +
                      '<input type="text" ng-model="searchOptions.sourceServer">' +
                      '<input type="text" ng-model="searchOptions.sourcePath">' +
                      '<input type="text" ng-model="searchOptions.destServer">' +
                      '<input type="text" ng-model="searchOptions.destPath">' +
                  '</fieldset>',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $model){
          $model.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
            if(modelValue){
              return {
                searchOptions: {
                  sourceServer: modelValue.searchOptions.sourceServer,
                  sourcePath: modelValue.searchOptions.sourcePath,
                  destServer: modelValue.searchOptions.destServer,
                  destPath: modelValue.searchOptions.destPath
                }
              };
            }
          });

          $model.$render = function() {
            if($model.$viewValue){
              $scope.searchOptions = {
                sourceServer: $model.$viewValue.searchOptions.sourceServer,
                sourceServer: $model.$viewValue.searchOptions.sourcePath,
                sourceServer: $model.$viewValue.searchOptions.destServer,
                sourceServer: $model.$viewValue.searchOptions.destPath
              }
            }
          };

          $model.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
            if(viewValue){
              return {
                searchOptions: {
                  sourceServer: viewValue.searchOptions.sourceServer,
                  sourcePath: viewValue.searchOptions.sourcePath,
                  destServer: viewValue.searchOptions.destServer,
                  destPath: viewValue.searchOptions.destPath
                }
              };
            }
          });
        }
      };
   });
```

And you will use the directive such as:
`<tbp-copy ng-model="ctrl.SomeHigherModel"></tbp-copy>`

and you will then be able to get the underlying values within the `ctrl.SomeHigherModel` that should equal to:

```
searchOptions: {
   sourceServer: 'some value',
   sourcePath: 'some value',
   destServer: 'some value',
   destPath: 'some value'
}
```

Comment: Wow, that looks great. Do you have a link to resources that you used to learn about detailed directives like you showed? Same for the information on the variables `$model.$formatters`, `$model.$render`, and `$model.$parsers`? Places I look tend to be very vague and only *use* the constructs from angular without explanation.

Comment: It's available on the very documentation page of AngularJS here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that I didn't need directives but they seemed to be the go-to solution in the places I looked, so I didn't know a simpler solution. I figured it out using ng-repeat with a data to model array, avoiding adding any DOM elements.